# Sections between \bibliography (with BibTeX) and \end{document}

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to include three sections after the \bibliography{name.bib} and before \end{document}

how can I show : the bibliography and the three sections after it in the table of contents **without** chapter number?

Davide

Here you can find an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1.tex}
....
\include{chapN.tex}
\appendix
\include{AppA}
\include{AppB}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Davide.bib}
\include{Summary}
\include{Aknow}
\include{CV}
\end{document}
```

instead of being not shown (bibliography) or shown as further appendices?
[image]

Comment: a MWE is something people can run to see the issue, we can not run that fragment. the chapters you are including will not be numbered if you use `\chapter*` rather than `\chapter` but other than that it is hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Add `\backmatter` before `\bibliography{Davide}`. By the way, no `.bib` extension should be used.

Comment: @David: Of course, but , as you can see from my edited message, this is not the case;

Comment: @egreg: will try so: I have had no problem with adding the .bib part (bibliography works fine, is this a case or is something happening that I am not seeing? )

Comment: Your edited question still leaves us mostly guessing as to the issue but egreg's guess is probably as good as any.

Comment: @David: ok in my edited question (with N=8, then 2 appendices, no bibliography, and 2 other appendices) this is not the case; In particulary, the summary in the picture is still declared with \chapter*{} so that is fine; but Aknowledgements and CV should appear without the letter in front (and same for the bibliography).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\backmatter` and `tocbibind`. Note that you have to use `\chapter` rather than `\chapter*`. Using `\include` is of course possible, I did not here in order to make the example self-contained.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy content

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\nocite{*} % to fill a bibliography
\kant[1-12]

\chapter{Two}
\kant[1-12]

\appendix
\chapter{App One}
\kant[1-5]

\chapter{App Two}
\kant[1-5]

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{valient} % one I have here

\chapter{Summary}
\kant[1-2]

\chapter{Acknowledgment}
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works for everything . Thanks a lot. How should i tag this topic as solved/closed?

Comment: @DaFraLo22 You're welcome. The green tick is sufficient to show that your problem has been solved.